# Is the time complexity of this function I found online O(n)?

Tags: javascript, time-complexity

I am trying to do [this problem on LeetCode](https://leetcode.com/problems/kth-largest-element-in-an-array/description/), and the following is the solution I found online:

```js
//  use quick select
var findKthLargest = function(nums, k) {
    var smaller = [];
    var larger = [];
    var pivot = nums[parseInt(nums.length/2)];
    var pivotCnt = 0;

    for (var i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
        var num = nums[i];      
  
        if(num > pivot) {
            larger.push(num);
        }
        else if(num < pivot) {
            smaller.push(num);
        }
        else {
            pivotCnt++;
        }
    }
  
    if (k <= larger.length) { // if larger includes k
        return findKthLargest(larger, k);
    }
    else if (k - larger.length - pivotCnt <= 0) { // k is part of pivot
        return pivot;
    }
    else { // if smaller inclues k
        return findKthLargest(smaller, k - larger.length - pivotCnt);
    }
};
```

Now I believe this is an O(n) solution, because worst case is that we iterate through the entire array, but I'm not certain.

Comment: but it's recursive?

Comment: It iterates through the array, but it's also calling itself recursively, so it may end up iterating through the array multiple times. Try to pick different values of `k` (like min, max, average values) and see how many times it might end up iterating through the array. It's not necessarily mathematically rigorous, but it'll give you a better sense of the complexity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function appears to be using some sort of divide and conquer approach.  For each call, it makes a single `O(n)` pass over the input array, bucketing values larger than, and smaller than, a certain pivot, into two separate arrays.  Then, it makes a recursive call on the appropriate subarray.  In an average case, it will divide the size of the input array by two, until a recursive call is made on just an array of size one, which is the base case.

I would estimate that the running time of this function is `O(n*lgn)`, which is typical for a divide and conquer algorithms.  Each call does `O(n)` work, and there would typically be `O(lgn)` number of recursive calls.

Comment: Well since n is changing each iteration, how come it wouldn't just be O(logn)?

Comment: @motioncity There are `O(logN)` number of _recursions_, i.e. calls to `findKthLargest()`, but in each iteration you are scanning the entire array.  This behaves like `O(n)`, because you touch each element once.

Comment: Yeah but n is changing at logn pace too, if anything why would it not be O(logN * logN)